# Take a number that starts with '0' from input (C++)

Tags: c++, input

My program takes several integers from standard input and treats them in a certain way, but when it comes to integers starting with `0` like `01`, `cin` only takes what is after the `0` and makes `01` `1`. Saying I want to keep the integer the way it is, how do I achieve that?

Comment: Store it as a string.

Comment: The strings 01 and 1 represent the same  number. Why do you expect them to be different?